# Beamer: Why does title of block become unreasonably large for roboto font

Tags: beamer, fonts, block

The MWE below produces a Beamer block with a too large title area.

Commenting out either of the second or third line fixes the problem.

How can I fix it if I want to keep both lines?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto} 
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{block}{Test}
Content
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Problem]
[image: Fixed by using standard font]
[image: Fixed by using no background color]

Comment: Your code gives the desired result on my computer.

Comment: using TexLive or MiKTeX?

Comment: MacTeX (=TeXLive) on El Capitan.

Comment: hm, then it seems to be a MiKTeX problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see it with an up-to-date TeXLeve. However, use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.9,sfdefault,light]{roboto}
```

or

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[scale=0.9,sfdefault,light]{roboto}
```

foe `xelatex` or `lualatex`

Comment: I am using MiKTeX. Your mentioning xelatex inspired me to try it though, and indeed solved the problem